# How to cancel NGRX store dispatch after some time in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx-store

I am calling two dispatchers in component like below,

```
this.store.dispatch(new topSectionAction(this.Id));  
this.store.dispatch(new bottomSectionAction(this.Id));
```

So two API calls will happen, based on first API data I want to cancel the second store dispatcher(means I want to cancel the second API request). How can I achieve this?

Comment: what about dispatching cancel action?

Comment: I didn't find anything like dispatching cancel action..If it is possible can you provide some code.. @AngularInDepth.com

Comment: it is probably better not to start dispatch that you don't need than to cancel it afterwards. It is difficult to propose something since it is unclear why there are two calls. But maybe you can use rx throttle operator to skip second call. Depending on your requirements other operators might help instead.

Comment: Can you combine the actions into one action, so it can determine if the second API needs to be called at all

Comment: Can you provide some code? @PavelAgarkov